# What could this error be? [REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]

Tags: android

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{app.app/app.app.activity.NotificacaoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'java.lang.String app.app_[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]' on a null
>   object reference
>
> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'java.lang.String app.app_[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]' on a null
>   object reference
>   app.app.persistence.WAPIService.getNotificacoes
>   (WAPIService.java:230)
>   app.app.activity.NotificacaoActivity.onStart
>   (NotificacaoActivity.java:65)

I could not understand what this error is, below, it follows the classes that the error quotes:
Notificacao:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        showProgress(true, "wait", false);

        WAPIService.getInstance().getNotificacoes(new FutureCallback<List<Notificacao>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Notificacao> result) {
                //listView.setAdapter(new NotificacaoAdapter(getContext(), result));
                if(!result.isEmpty()) {
                    List<Notificacao> lidas = new ArrayList<Notificacao>();
                    List<Notificacao> naoLidas = new ArrayList<Notificacao>();

                    for(Notificacao n : result){
                        if((n.Status == 10 && n.Tipo != 5 && n.Tipo != 10 && n.Tipo != 15 && n.Tipo != 20) ){//Teste com 20 para dividir
                            naoLidas.add(n);
                        } else {
                            lidas.add(n);
                        }
                    }

                    if (getFragmentRefreshListenerLidas() != null) {
                        getFragmentRefreshListenerLidas().onRefresh(new NotificacaoAdapter(getContext(), lidas));
                    }

                    if (getFragmentRefreshListenerNaoLidas() != null) {
                        getFragmentRefreshListenerNaoLidas().onRefresh(new NotificacaoAdapter(getContext(), naoLidas));
                    }
                }
                showProgress(false, "", true);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                showProgress(false, "", true);
                Toast("Erro ao buscar notificações");
                Log.e(TAG, "Erro ao buscar notificações: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Wapi:
This class goes to the server and I look for notifications:

public void getNotificacoes(final FutureCallback> callback) {
    JsonObject usuarioId = new JsonObject();
    usuarioId.addProperty("id_usuario", ((ApplicationUtils) context.getApplicationContext()).getUsuario().Id);

```
wapiConn.invokeApi("notification", "get", usuarioId, JsonObject.class, new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JsonObject result) {
        try {
            List<Notificacao> notificacoes = JsonEntityParser.parseResults(result.getAsJsonArray("notifications"),
                    wapiConn.getMobileServiceClient().getGsonBuilder().create(), Notificacao.class);
            //Chamando CallBack da tela de login / registro
            callback.onSuccess(notificacoes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callback.onFailure(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        callback.onFailure(t);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the call to **context.getApplicationContext()).getUsuario()** returns null and you get the NPE when trying to get the user's Id. Maybe the user is not logged in so that's why there is no corresponding object in the ApplicationContext.